# Use ng-if or ng-switch to switch between to href's (Ionic)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Working on an Ionic project, where the user can add drinks to his favourite list. The drinks come from 2 views. View 1: General list of drinks and view 2: The Newly added drinks. This means that each view has its own detail page.

So when the user goes to the view My Favorites, he will get to see his favourite drinks coming from view 1 and view 2. So when clicking for example on a drink belonging to view 1 it will have a different href then a drink coming from view 2.

Here is my code of the Favourites view:

```
  <ion-content class="padding">

        <div class="row responsive-md" >
            <div class="col col-33">    
                <div>
                    <!-- View 1 GENERAL LIST OF DRINKS-->
                    <a href="#/app/gin-mixes-detail/{{drink.id}}" class="grid-gin-mixes" ng-repeat="drink in favs = (user.current.favorites) track by $index">
                        <img class="gin-mixes-placeholder" ng-src="{{drink.src}}">
                        <p>{{drink.title}}</p>
                    </a>

                    <!-- View 2 NEWLY ADDED DRINKS -->
                    <a href="#/app/newly-added-detail/{{drink.id}}" class="grid-gin-mixes" ng-repeat="drink in favs = (user.current.favorites) track by $index">
                        <img class="gin-mixes-placeholder" ng-src="{{drink.src}}">
                        <p>{{drink.title}}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
  </ion-content>
```

What I need is when the user clicks on a drink say from view 2 it will know to use the correct href. So I need to know how to best solve this with ng-if or ng-switch. And how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have separate template, also you don't need to maintain different template. Rather I'd have `ng-href` which will conditionally render `href` by taking use of `{{}}` interpolation.

**Markup**

```
ng-href="{{'#/app/'+(drinkType=='general'?'gin-mixes-detail':'newly-added-detail')+/drink.id}}"
```